# Set the colour of text in a QPushButton in PyQt4 using Python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I would like to create some clickable blue text on my GUI, kind of like a HTML hyperlink!
I am using Python 2.6 and PyQt4. I have managed to set the text colour of a QLabel before, but cannot remember how i did that, even if i did its not clickable. So I have moved onto a QPushButton that I can make flat like so:

```
testbutton = qt.QPushButton("Test")
testbutton.setFlat(True)
```

So far all my searches have turned up c++ and c# methods and i cant seem to find a python equivalent!

Any ideas on how to change the text colour or even different ways of accomplishing this entirely would be most welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html).

```
testbutton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: blue}')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`palette`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qwidget.html#palette-prop) property of your `QPushButton` and apply your blue color to its `ButtonText` color role:

```
testbutton = qt.QPushButton("Test")
testbutton.setFlat(True)

palette = qt.QPalette(testbutton.palette()) # make a copy of the palette
palette.setColor(qt.QPalette.ButtonText, qt.QColor('blue'))
testbutton.setPalette(palette) # assign new palette
```

Comment: Also worked perfectly, but as the other solution was a bit simpler using only one line of code i think i will use that, unless there is a reason why using the palette option is a better idea? or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: I think the palette can be seen as the 'old style' solution. In my opinion, the more flexible way is to use a css file and assign its content to the QApplication: `myQApp.setStyleSheet(open(myCssFile).read())`. By doing so you can change the look and feel of your application without having to modify a line of code. Qt's Css provides various ways to adress widgets; see [Selector Types](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)

Answer (score 0):

```
testbutton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00FF00; color: #00FF00;")
```

where:
"background-color" is color of You button.
"color" is color of the text of button.